# Failing to replace Android preference file while the app is running

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app has a backup restore feature which allows me to save both the preferences and database files and restore them.
This works fine IF I close / restart the app t the end of the process.
What I would like is to be able to first restore the pref files and reload it without closing the app.

To do so I'm copying the external pref file to the path of the existing one.
Then I'm trying to reload the preferences but this is what's not working properly.

I'm calling

```
this.preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String res = this.preferences.getString("pref_1", null);
```

But this is not returning the value of the file I just restored (unless I close/restart the app)

Is there a way to reload the preferences from the pref file while the app is running?

Comment: Can you post the writing to `SharedPreferences` code?

Comment: This works fine as reopening the app shows the new preferences. The problem is that I cannot get the app to reload the preferences which is fine by the code I posted

Comment: it may be that your shared preference is bound to `this` which is most likely to be your activity. Have you tried replacing it with something like `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`?

Comment: Yes I was initially trying to load it with the private mode flag but it doesn't change anything. I also added some sleep 2 seconds after copying the file without any success